# Symfony 2.8/3.0 upgrade: how to deal with form types with variable parameters?

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony, symfony-2.8

Let's say I create custom form types as services, as it is described in the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service). But I want 2 "gender" custom types, with 2 different input parameters, which I was doing like this in Symfony 2.7:

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    genders1:
        m: Male
        f: Female
    genders2: # This makes no sense at all, but it is for the example purpose!
        h: Horse
        t: Turtle
```

And then, I was declaring 2 services like this:

```
<!-- src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.xml -->
<service id="app.form.type.gender1" class="AppBundle\Form\Type\GenderType">
    <argument>%genders1%</argument>
    <tag name="form.type" alias="gender1" />
</service>

<service id="app.form.type.gender2" class="AppBundle\Form\Type\GenderType">
    <argument>%genders2%</argument>
    <tag name="form.type" alias="gender2" />
</service>
```

As you can see, I was using the **same** `GenderType` class for 2 custom form types (with the `gender1` and `gender2` aliases), which I could use like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('field1', 'gender1')
    ->add('field2', 'gender2');
```

This allowed me to add some common logic in only one class (`GenderType`) with different input parameters (I have many more possibilities than 2 in this example).

But as of Symfony 2.8, adding a field using the service alias is deprecated. The class name has to be passed as the second argument instead, like this:

```
$builder->add('field1', GenderType::class)
```

So how can I make the difference between my 2 services (each of them not having the same input parameters)?

Creating `Gender1Type` and `Gender2Type` extending an abstract `GenderType` class would be really painful, as I would have to create a lot of classes with empty content.

Do you have any idea on how to implement my pattern in Symfony 2.8, keeping services with different input parameters, but not creating a lot of classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after digging this topic a bit more, [someone already asked](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/15079#issuecomment-114884704) the question directly in the [PR concerning this change](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/15079) in Symfony 2.8.

And the answer is that the pattern I was doing is not possible anymore, so I see 2 solutions to my problem:

- Create as many classes as I had services for my custom types instead of using all the time the same class, and make these classes extend an abstract one (in my example: create `Gender1Type` and `Gender2Type` classes that extend a `AbstractGenderType` abstract class)
- Keep only one class, but add options to it to pass my specific parameters.

Comment: Yep.  I ran into the same thing and came to the same conclusion.  There are advantages in using class names but in this case I still don't see a clear advantage over the original design.  Oh well.